# What are some easy-to-implement scaffolding systems?

Tags: php, database-development, cms

Often when stating a new project I'll require a *"quick 'n' dirty"* content management solution.

Ideally something that can read my database schema and generated HTML forms.

Previously I've used; [phpMyEdit](http://www.phpmyedit.org/) and [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) but they are lacking is key areas.

My wish list woulds be:

1. Database independent
2. Foreign key aware
3. Handles views as-well-as tables
4. Generates modern HTML and CSS
5. AJAX interface.

What's your swiss army knife when it comes to CMS on a project?

Comment: What do you mean by CMS? Content management system? Because for that I usually think of things like Drupal, Plone, ExpressionEngine, Joomla, etc.

Comment: I think he means something like Rails scaffolds or phpMyAdmin - a way to manage database content before the proper UI is in place.

Comment: @Fishtoaster I'm confused though how to reword it though. What category *is* phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Hell if I know.  "Data management system" maybe?  "Instant CMS" isn't that bad a descriptor.

Comment: @Fishtoaster nailed it!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for "scaffolding", where the software generates views that allow users to maintain the data without you having to do much or any work.  If you must stick with PHP, then look at CakePHP. http://book.cakephp.org/view/105/Scaffolding

But two quick suggestions for you. Look at this site: http://www.phpscaffold.com/

Second suggestion: Consider switching to Python/Django or Ruby on Rails.  Both of those are better than what PHP has to offer in terms of scaffolding.  There may be something in PHP somewhere that's as good, but I have not seen it.  CakePHP is the closest I know of.